# Pivot text data in R from columns to row

Tags: r, text, dplyr, pivot

I have a problem trying to pivot text data in R from columns to rows. The data has numeric and text columns but the text columns won't pivot? I have tried using `dplyr` but will use anything that works?

Code

```
long=pivot_longer(original, c('Col1','Col2','Col3' ))
```

[image]

Dput:

```
structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Sanj", "Rob"), Date = c("12/08/2020", 
"13/08/2020", "14/08/2020"), Col1 = c(20, 60, 40), Col2 = c("blue", 
"red", "black"), Col3 = c(100, 233, 500)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in again.  Instead,  use `dput` to create a text version of your data and paste that into your question, so that we only need to cut and paste to get your data

Comment: The usual data.frame is a list of vectors which all have the same length. A vector can only hold one data type simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you, That is great :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution:

```
setDT(dt)
melt(dt, id=1:2, measure = 3:5)
```

Comment: Thank you, beautifully elegant and simple solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all types to `character`:

```
long %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Name, Date)) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  rename(`new col` = name,
         Value = value)



   Name  Date       `new col` Value
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>
1 Joe   12/08/2020 Col1      20   
2 Sanj  13/08/2020 Col1      60   
3 Rob   14/08/2020 Col1      40   
4 Joe   12/08/2020 Col2      blue 
5 Sanj  13/08/2020 Col2      red  
6 Rob   14/08/2020 Col2      black
7 Joe   12/08/2020 Col3      100  
8 Sanj  13/08/2020 Col3      233  
9 Rob   14/08/2020 Col3      500
```

Comment: Thank you, That is great :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (tidyr 1.1.1)

```
library(tidyverse) 
pivot_longer(df,
             -c(Name, Date),
             values_transform = list(value = as.character))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Name  Date       name  value
  <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>
1 Joe   12/08/2020 Col1  20   
2 Joe   12/08/2020 Col2  blue 
3 Joe   12/08/2020 Col3  100  
4 Sanj  13/08/2020 Col1  60   
5 Sanj  13/08/2020 Col2  red  
6 Sanj  13/08/2020 Col3  233  
7 Rob   14/08/2020 Col1  40   
8 Rob   14/08/2020 Col2  black
9 Rob   14/08/2020 Col3  500
```

Comment: Thank you, That is great :-)

Comment: Glad the answer was helpful. If the answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the up arrow